# How to verify if file has contents to marshal from ioutil.ReadFile in Go

Tags: file, go, io

I am trying to use a file instead of a DB to get a prototype up and running. I have a program that (1) reads existing content from the file to a map, (2) takes JSON POSTs that add content to the map, (3) on exit, writes to the file.

First, the file is not being created. Then I created an empty file. It is not being written to. 
I am trying to read the file, determine if there is existing content. If there is not existing content, create a blank map. If there is existing content, unmarshal it into a new map.

```
  func writeDB() {
    eventDBJSON, err := json.Marshal(eventDB)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err2 := ioutil.WriteFile("/Users/sarah/go/dat.txt", eventDBJSON, 0777)
    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }
}

func main() {

    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/sarah/go/dat.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if dat == nil {
        eventDB = DB{
            events: map[string]event{},
        }
    } else {
        if err2 := json.Unmarshal(dat, &eventDB); err2 != nil {
            panic(err2)
        }
    }

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.POST("/join", JoinEvent)
    router.POST("/create", CreateEvent)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))

    defer writeDB()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the server to ever reach `defer writeDB()`.

http.ListenAndServe blocks, and if it did return anything, you log.Fatal that, which exits your app at that point.

You can't intercept all ways an app can exit, getting SIGKILL, machine loss of power, etc.

I'm assuming you really just want to write some code, bounce the server, repeat

If that's the case, then Ctrl-C is good enough.

If you want to write your file on Ctrl-C, look at the [signal](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/) package.

Also, defer on the last line of a function really has no purpose as defer basically means "do this last".

Answer (score 0):

you can use [(*os.File).Stat()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Stat) to get a file's [FileInfo](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) which contain its size

```
   file, err := os.Open( filepath ) 
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    fi, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }

   s := fi.Size()
```